# Serialize extracted (custom attribute) value in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-aggregate

I am using Extractor for querying based on custom attributes. Here is the sample code.

```
@Override
public void extract(Object arg0, Object arg1, ValueCollector valueCollector) {
    //date =  domainVO.getDomainDate();
    //valueCollector.addObject(age);
    ValueReader valueReader = (ValueReader)arg0;
    valueReader.read("domain.collectionData[any].status", (ValueCallback<String>)(value) -> {
        valueCollector.addObject(value);
    });
}
```

Custom attribute configuration

```
AttributeConfig attributeConfig = new AttributeConfig().setName("status")
            .setExtractorClassName("com.sample.test.extractor.DomainValueExtractor");
```

Here client receives the entire entry object while querying the data.

Is it possible to fetch the custom attribute 'status' from client ?